# Microsoft Teams recording question

Tags: microsoft-teams

Please could you answer a query for me; yesterday on TEAMS I noticed my 
camera icon in the top right of my screen was red during a TEAMS chat. Does 
that mean it was being recorded?
Are all TEAMS meetings recorded, and does that also include anything 
written into the chat panel on the right? And if so, can those recordings 
be deleted? (where are they stored?). I'm thinking of my students. 
Finally, do TEAMS users know they are being recorded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure which icon you are referring to. To the top right there is a status icon that will show that you are busy (red) when you are in a meeting. This does not mean that the meeting was recorded.

---

You can read all about the recording feature here: [Record a meeting in Teams](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/record-a-meeting-in-teams-34dfbe7f-b07d-4a27-b4c6-de62f1348c24)

Not all meetings are recorded, one of the attendees will have to initiate the recording. The users license will determine if they can start the recording ([ref](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/record-a-meeting-in-teams-34dfbe7f-b07d-4a27-b4c6-de62f1348c24#bkmk_whocanstartorstoparecording))

Everyone in the meeting will get a banner on the top clearly saying that the meeting is being recorded. Everything on-screen is recording, including shared media.

The chat is kept in chat history, this is saved independent of a recording starting or not.

The recording is saved to Microsoft Stream, where it can also be deleted. [Reference.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/delete-a-meeting-recording-in-teams-b1ff8102-72da-4a6c-9979-d03a55d9b65d)

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer.
As you have asked about the icon it was camera icon in the top right of my screen was red during a TEAMS chat.

Comment: I am still not sure what you are referring to as the camera icon - could it be the one with your profile picture on it? Unless you were in a video meeting there is no way it was recorded apart from the chat history being saved (it is by default).

Comment: Hi Rune, yes it was video recording. My bad, I understood now. It's not actually right on camera icon it is before that and when I go on it it says the persons name and then started the recording. Everything is clear now.
Thank you very much.